# Microsoft SQL server 2008 sp2 supported

Tags: 2011

Is Microsoft SQL server 2008 sp2 supported for the Content broker database in SDL Tridion 2011 sp1?

Comment: +1 for a clear and specific first question on Tridion Stack Exchange, though we *could* give you a hard time asking you what research you did. Questions show what you've tried and prompt more than a yes/no answer will do definitely do better. Welcome and we're looking forward to your participation on the site.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 is supported for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. SQL Server 2008 R2 is supported but deprecated (support for it is dropped in the next releases of SDL Tridion). This (and more) information can be found in the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_745H5HKKRKLR5567GHH) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

The Hotfix rollup, or SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 added support for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2. The actual version Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP2 was never supported for 2011.

Comment: @Bart that depends on where you look. In the 'Content Delivery Prerequisites' chapter, 2008 SP2 actually is listed as supported, but deprecated. Your link comes from the 'Content Data Store' chapter, so the docs are ambiguous.

Comment: That is Windows Server 2008 SP2, the operating system, not the database

Comment: Oh you are right. Do you want my 1 point? :P

Comment: no that's okay, I saw that after my first edit and then saw that the versions are a complete mess with R2 SP1 etc. You started off the right path ;)